# How do I convert this sql to sequelize

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have this query, how do I convert this query to sequelize, I know I can run sequelize.query but would like to know how this can be converted.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  user_id,
  user_name,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE amount > 30) AS over30,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE amount <= 30 AND amount > 0) AS under30,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE amount >= '-14'::integer AND amount < 0) AS less14,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE amount < '-14'::integer) AS over14,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE amount > 30) + 
    count(*) FILTER (WHERE amount <= 30 AND amount > 0) + 
    count(*) FILTER (WHERE amount >= '-14'::integer AND amount < 0) +
    count(*) FILTER (WHERE amount < '-14'::integer) as totals
FROM amount_table 
WHERE user_id IS NOT null and user_id = any(array['111','112'])
GROUP BY user_id, user_name
```

Comment: No need for `SELECT DISTINCT` here, your `GROUP BY` returns no duplicates. (That combination just make people confused.)

Comment: And no need for `user_id IS NOT null`, the other condition will only be true for non-null user_id's.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the squelize version of your query.
The Amount model is defined in this Sequelize code to match your database schema once Sequelize instance is initially set up.
To retrieve the data with the given attributes, criteria, and grouping, the findAll function is being utilized.
The aggregation functions and filters used in your SQL query are built using Sequelize's sequelize.fn and sequelize.literal functions in the attributes array. Additionally, sequelize.literal is used to calculate the totals.
The user_id is used to filter the results using the where clause.
In order to obtain plain JSON results, I finally set raw: true.

try this code:

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Op } = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('your_database', 'your_username', 'your_password', {
  dialect: 'postgres', // Adjust the dialect as per your database
  host: 'your_host',
  port: 5432, // Adjust the port as per your database
});

// Define your Amount model
const Amount = sequelize.define('Amount', {
  user_id: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING, // Change the data type as per your database schema
    allowNull: false,
  },
  user_name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING, // Change the data type as per your database schema
  },
  amount: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER, // Change the data type as per your database schema
  },
});

// Build the query using Sequelize
const result = await Amount.findAll({
  attributes: [
    'user_id',
    'user_name',
    [sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.literal("CASE WHEN amount > 30 THEN 1 ELSE null END")), 'over30'],
    [sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.literal("CASE WHEN amount <= 30 AND amount > 0 THEN 1 ELSE null END")), 'under30'],
    [sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.literal("CASE WHEN amount >= -14 AND amount < 0 THEN 1 ELSE null END")), 'less14'],
    [sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.literal("CASE WHEN amount < -14 THEN 1 ELSE null END")), 'over14'],
    [sequelize.literal("count(*)"), 'totals'],
  ],
  where: {
    user_id: {
      [Op.not]: null,
      [Op.in]: ['111', '112'],
    },
  },
  group: ['user_id', 'user_name'],
  raw: true, // To get plain JSON result
});

console.log(result);
```

Hope it works :)